# Cypress, Vuex access module store state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, cypress

I have an application that uses vuex. The Vuex is setup so that each module has its own state.

Example setup:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    app: window.application,
    view: ''
  },
  modules: {
    checkout,
    account,
    navigation
  }
```

Then the module has its own state.
Example:

```
const checkout = {
    namespaced: true, // IMPORTANT for modules
    state: {
        site: null,
        deliveryType: 'homeDelivery',
        deliveryOption: 'standardDelivery',
        manualAddressActive: false,
    }
}
```

I've initiated the app like so:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#baseMountTarget',
    api,
    i18n,
    router,
    store,
    render: h => h(Base)
});

if(window.Cypress) {
    window.app = app;
}
```

Now my question is how do i access the modules state in cypress? By doing the following i can access the base state just not the module state and i can't work out how to access the module state

```
context('DeliveryOption', () => {
   describe('Delivery option home delivery', () => {
        it('Should have active class for home delivery', () => {
            const getStore = () => cy.window().its('app.$store');

            getStore().its('state.deliveryType').should('equal', 'homeDelivery');
        });
})
```

Comment: That seems like a *terrible* idea. Cypress shouldn't have to know that your app is using *Vue*, let alone which specific state container.

Comment: Ok cypress is new to me so maybe I've miss understood its usage. Could you explain a better way of testing the state?

Comment: You don't test the state, you test whether your end user can interact with the site successfully. Your end users don't care what frontend frameworks you're using! What does the state's delivery type being home delivery actually mean for them? Perhaps the form takes different inputs in that mode, so test that they can create an order with a home address.